# Displaying AdMob banner at bottom of screen

Tags: android, admob, android-relativelayout

My `AdMob` banner displays on top of the screen instead of displaying at the bottom.

This is my code:

```
adView = new AdView(mSingleton);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER); 
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx");

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
  .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
  .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
mLayout.addView(adView, params);
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You do not have to logcat reports that there is no space?

Comment: No, i don't have any report.

Comment: It will not be an exception, but just a message. Admob nothing says?

Comment: It says only "App index is not enabled" but I don't think it is important...

Comment: You just created an ad? Try to wait a little longer.

Comment: Yes. It displays succesfully, but at the top of the screen.

Comment: It seems to me that something is wrong with a free space... Try using a different method of disposing.

Comment: please attach your xml file code, we will be able to help better

Comment: But your `addrule` functions do the right job for me lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it!

Change the gravity of the Layout containing the adView:

```
((layoutType) layout).setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Quick, easy solution.  Worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

relace your adview code with this

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx">

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: First his question already has an accepted answer. Second explain why your code should solve the problem, so that others with similar question might find your solution helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView 
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="put ad id here">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Replace your java code for AdView.

```
 adView = new AdView(mSingleton);
  adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER); 
  adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx");


  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
  params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
  .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
  .build();
  adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  mLayout.addView(adView, params);
```

With this

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The line `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in your adView in xml is important. Place that and try it.

Mostly got it from https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: It works, but it covers my main layout, so I have a black screen with an ad at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't have an xml file, because I have only an AbsoluteLayout (mLayout) added progammatically.

Comment: where are you doing SetContentView, I mean on what are you doing SetContentView ?

Comment: In my activity.java: 

mLayout = new AbsoluteLayout(this);

      mLayout.addView(mSurface);


      setContentView(mLayout);



Thanks.